# ITunes Artwork extension error when uploading a new version of the application to the store using App Uploader

Tags: ios

I'm getting an an error when trying to upload a new version of my app to the store using the Application Uploader. It says:
"Icon specified in the Info.plist CFBundleIconFile does not have an extension:iTunesArtwork"
From what I can tell, the iTunesArtwork is not supposed to have an extension. What do I do?